# Append/prepend not work with load? And some questions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two problems with append/prepend on JQuery. My code:

```
function toselect(f,d){
    $('#workcont').remove('h2').load('pages/' + f + '.html #' + d).prepend('<h2>Some text</h2>');
    calculate();
}
```

Div on default is clear `<div id="workcont"></div>`

Problems:

1. `prepend` add code for a second and then disappears, why? (not hide! removed)
2. `remove('h2')` don't remove added by prepend code. (if prepared wil be work) It's some function in my .js file.
3. function `calculate();` does not apply to loaded content. Use with live() also not work.

Comment: `load` is async function, if you want some actions to be performed on loaded content - supply a callback function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try prepend in callback

```
function toselect(f,d){
    $('#workcont').load('pages/' + f + '.html #' + d,function(){
    $(this).remove('h2').prepend('<h2>Расчет стоимости</h2>');
    $('#workcont').calculate();
});

}
```

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you! All works. But i'm delete selector before clculate() to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

load has a callback function , the reason is that load work async and hence the prepend add the html before load completes , you may try like this

```
function toselect(f,d){   

$('#workcont').remove('h2').load('pages/' + f + '.html #' + d, function(){

  $("#workcont").prepend("your html");
  calculate();

 });

}
```